# How to handle 'A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client' error without turning ValidatePage off

Tags: c#, asp.net, wysiwyg, validate-request

I have a wysiwyg editor on my page and its content contains '<' character. Is there a way to handle this error without turning off **validateRequest**

I am using a custom framework and my page is a webcontrol (.ascx) in it, so I can't turn off validation only for that page; I have to do it for whole site. Simply I don't want to turn it off just because of one page with wysiwyg editor.

Is there a way to make it work without turning the validation off?

Comment: At what moment is the error shown? Upon POST or when accessing certain variables?

Comment: when a postback happens on the page

Comment: Normally, wysiwyg editor should encode the content at client-side and decode at server-side for you. What wysiwyg editor are you using?

Comment: I use ckeditor, but i am posting its content in jQuery for autosaving. So there is no postback

Comment: What editor are you using?